# Can't find module in vuejs error, but still builds fine

Tags: vue.js

I'm getting an odd error when I run my vue code (npm run serve), it complains of a few missing modules but the code ends up running fine

```
70:31 Cannot find module '../components/modal/CreateBucketModal'.
    68 | import router from '../router';
    69 | import ApiService from '../services/apiService';
  > 70 | import CreateBucketModal from '../components/modal/CreateBucketModal'
```

The path is correct as it is clearly running fine despite the error

the problem arises when I go to build my vuejs app for production, it won't build because of the error

Comment: that is strange, the only variation I see code-wise is there's no semicolon on your last import.. but that shouldn't impact anything. I've seen this error only when my file paths weren't correctly defined. Are you sure that last one is right? Could be you meant to do `'../../components/modal/CreateBucketModal'` or `'./components/modal/CreateBucketModal'`depending on where you are in the tree structure.

Comment: @I'mOnlyVueman I solved it by adding ".vue" to CreateBucketModal so its '../components/modal/CreateBucketModal.vue"

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't use the `.vue` file extension on any of my component imports. I'm wondering if it has to do with the structure of the component you're importing from. All of my components are single-file components. If yours aren't that could be a factor. I'd probably need to see more code to make sense of it.

Comment: Did you create the project with the Vue CLI? If so, what version (from `npm run serve` I'm assuming v3)? If not, what are you using the build the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I solved it by adding ".vue" to CreateBucketModal so its '../components/modal/CreateBucketModal.vue".
>   Is there a way around this?

Being able to resolve single-file Vue components without the `.vue` extension is down to how Webpack is configured, specifically the [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve#resolveextensions) configuration.

The default for a Vue CLI v3 project is

```js
resolve {
  extensions: [
    '.wasm',
    '.mjs',
    '.js',
    '.jsx',
    '.vue', //  note this entry
    '.json'
  ]
}
```

I can only assume then that you have modified your Webpack config. If you are manipulating `resolve.extensions`, try adding to it instead of overwriting it, eg

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve.extensions.push('.some.new.extension')
    // instead of config.resolve.extensions = ['.some.new.extension']
  }
}
```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html